# Ошибка List index out of range, не знаю как её исправить

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def drawBoard(board): # Изобразить структуру данных игрового поля.
  tensDigitsLine = ' ' #Создать место для чисел вниз по левой стороне поля.
  for i in range(1,6):
     tensDigitsLine += (' ' * 9) + str(i)

  #Вывести числа в верхней части поля.
  print(tensDigitsLine)
  print(' '+('0123456789' * 6))
  print()


  #Вывести каждый из 15 рядов

  for row in range(15):

    if row < 10:
        extraSpace = ' '

    else:
        extraSpace = ''

    boardRow = ' '
    for column in range(60):
        boardRow += board[column][row]
```

Comment: вы понимаете смысл этой ошибки и причину по которой она возникает в вашем коде?

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю что за данные у вас передаются в эту функцию и каких они размерности, но в этой строчке у вас один из индексов выходит за границы массива `boardRow += board[column][row]`, либо `column`, либо `row`, попробуйте убрать сначала одно, потом другое, и посмотрите, при какой выдается ошибка.